# How can I access a Python package in AWS CodeArtifact from a Glue Job?

Tags: pip, aws-glue, aws-codeartifact

I'm writing a Glue job that requires a custom package we host in our AWS CodeArtifact repository. I haven't found how to install a PyPi package from AWS CodeArtifact since all the instructions involve reading from a S3 folder that IMHO defeats the purpose of CodeArtifact.

How would you do this?

Comment: I'm stuck with this as well.  Was able to get things set up using job parameter --python-modules-installer-option to set --index-url with the URL for the CodeArtifact repo.  Problem is that the token must be part of the URL, and it expires every 12 hrs.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-and-optimize-python-package-management-for-aws-glue-pyspark-jobs-with-aws-codeartifact/ describes a solution using step functions to first generate the token, then use it to form the index url, then use that as a job parameter.  Super clunky!  I'm still looking for a better solution!

Comment: @teejay as weird as it sounds, I think it cannot be done.